# valueOf() method of String class and other wrapper classes

Tags: java

```
System.out.println( Integer.valueOf(1).equals(Long.valueOf(1)) );   // false
```

Above print statement prints false, when using `Integer` and `Long` classes `valueOf()` methods respectively, the reason is very clear the two objects (`Integer` and the `Long`) have different types so they are not equal.

But, if passing **integer value 1** and **long value 1l** to `valueOf()` method of string class, my print statement prints true

```
System.out.println( String.valueOf(1).equals(String.valueOf(1l)) );  // true
```

I am not able to understand what is exact difference between them. 
I need explanation for that.

Comment: Read the javadoc. Both return the same String: "1". And "1" is equal to "1".

Comment: Because the String representation(s) of `(int) 1` and `(long) 1` are equal. Also `(((int) 1) == ((long) 1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is on the implementation of [`Integer#equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

You don't enter the `if` statement because they are of different *types*.

In the second version you are getting `true` because.. 1 is the same in String representation.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `Integer` and `Long` are **different** types, so `equals` returns **false**.

However, when comparing two `String`s, if the value is the **same** (which is), `equals` returns **true**.

Conversion of `Long` or `Integer` to `String` is determined by the number it represents. `Integer` 1 and `Long` 1 have the same digits, so converting both to `String` give same results (`"1"`).

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, the `String` representation of the number one is equal independent of what you use to retrieve that value.  The `valueOf` method is overridden to work with ints and longs.

Your first experiment and your second experiment are not at all comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple; regardless of whether the number 1 comes from an int, long, byte, or whatever, String.valueOf(1) -> "1". So you're running System.out.println("1".equals("1")), which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because in Java there are specific suffixes, for long (1L), float (1.4f) and double (-3.123d)..

Without any suffix, e.g. 1234 its being assumed to be an int. If its for example 3.1234 it would be assumed that its a double.

It doesnt matter if the suffix is in upper or lower case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.valueOf(1).equals(Long.valueOf(1)) // false
```

Yes, because `Integer.ValueOf(1)` result in an `Integer` instance and `Integer.equals(Object)` expects that the `Object` is a type `Integer` too.

```
 String.valueOf(1).equals(String.valueOf(1l)) // true
```

Results is true, because both `String.valueOf(1)` and `String.valueOf(1l)` results in a string representing a number with plain character of digit.  For example:

```
String.valueOf(12335454654465421L); will result in "12335454654465421"
```